# No se aplican los estilos css propios en la página web usando spring, pero sí los de bootstrap

Tags: html, css, spring-boot, spring, thymeleaf

Básicamente estoy creando una barra de navegación sencilla utilizando bootstrap, cuyos css de bootstrap funcionan. Pero también intento usar un css propio y no se aplica al ejecutar la página web, pero sí al ejecutar la página en visual studio con live server o similares. El código del encabezado es un fragmento que inserto con thymeleaf con th:insert.
Código del fragmento que intento insertar (top.html):

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/templates/aparte/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="er.css">
</head>

<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark box-shadow">

        <ul class="navbar-nav barTop">
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link text-gray-600" href="/profesores">Profesores</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link text-gray-600" href="/coches">Coches</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link text-gray-600" href="/alumnos">Alumnos</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</body>

</html>
```

Página en la que inserto el top (linea 6):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head th:insert="librerias::librerias">

</head>

<body>

    <div th:insert="top"></div>

    <h1>Cosas Coches</h1>
    
    

    <table class="table table-hover">
        <thead class="table-dark bg-info text-white">
            <tr>
                <td>ID</td>
                <td>Marca</td>
                <td>Matricula</td>
                <td>Modelo</td>
                <td>FechaITV</td>
                <td colspan="2">Acciones</td>
                
                
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr th:if="${listaCoches.Empty}">
            <td colspan="2">No hay coches </td>
        <tr th:each="coche:${listaCoches}">
            <td>
                <a th:href="@{/coches/{id}(id=${coche.id})}" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">
                    <span th:text="${coche.id}"></span>
                    </a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <span th:text="${coche.marca}"> </span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <span th:text="${coche.matricula}"> </span>
            </td>
            <td>
            <span th:text="${coche.modelo}"></span>
            </td>
            <td>
            <span th:text="${coche.fechaITV}"></span>
            </td>
        <td> 
                    <a th:attr="data-target='#modal-edit'+${coche.id}" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-edit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm text-white pointer">
                    Modificar
                    </a>
                </td>
                <td> 
                    <a th:attr="data-target='#modal-delete'+${coche.id}" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-delete" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm text-white pointer">
                    Eliminar
                    </a>
                </td>
        
        
        </tbody>
    </table>
    
    <div>
            <div>
                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#crearCoche"> + </button>
                
            </div>
            
            <div> 
                    
        </div>

                <div class="modal fade" id="crearCoche">
                    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <h4 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Crear coche/a</h4>
                            <button class="close" type="button" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">x</span>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <p class="error-text">Introduce el nombre para el nuevo coche
                            <!--formulario nombre a editar-->
                            <form action="#" th:action="@{/coches/add/}" th:object="${cocheNuevo}" method="post"> 
                                <div class"form-row">
                                <div class="form-group mt-1">
                                    <label for="Marca">Marca</label>
                                    <input type="text" th:field="*{marca}" class="form-control" id="marca" placeholder="marca" /> 
                                    <label for="matricula">Matricula</label>
                                    <input type="text" th:field="*{matricula}" class="form-control" id="matricula" placeholder="matricula" />
                                    <label for="modelo">Modelo</label>
                                    <input type="text" th:field="*{modelo}" class="form-control" id="modelo" placeholder="modelo" />
                                    <label for="fecha">Fecha ITV</label>
                                    <input type="date" th:field="*{fechaITV}" class="form-control" id="fecha" placeholder="fechaITV" />
                                    
                                </div>
                                </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <button class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Cancelar</button>
                                    <input type="submit" value="Crear" class="btn btn-primary float-right"/>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- fin create modal-->
                
                <!--delete modal-->
                <div th:each="coche:${listaCoches}">
                <div class="modal fade" th:id="modal-delete+${coche.id}">
                    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <h4 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Borrar</h4>
                            <button class="close btn btn-danger" type="button" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">x</span>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <p class="error-text">Seguro que quieres borrar este coche?
                            <strong><span th:text="${coche.marca}+' '+${coche.matricula}"> </span></strong></p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <button class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Cancelar</button>
                                    <a th:href="@{/coches/delete/{id}(id=${coche.id})}"> 
                                    <span class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" value="delete">Borrar</span>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                <!-- fin delete modal-->
                
                <!-- edit modal-->
                <div th:each="coche:${listaCoches}">
                    <div class="modal fade" th:id="modal-edit+${coche.id}">
                    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <h4 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modificar</h4>
                            <button class="close btn btn-danger" type="button" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">x</span>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <p class="error-text">Introduce matricula nueva para el coche:
                            <strong><span th:text="${coche.matricula}"> </span></strong></p>
                            <!--formulario nombre a editar-->
                            <form action="#" th:action="@{/coches/edit/{id}(id=${coche.id})}" th:object="${cocheaEditar}" method="post"> 
                                <div class"form-row">
                                <div class="form-group mt-1"> 
                                    <label for="texto">Matricula</label>
                                    <input type="text" th:field="*{matricula}" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail" th:attr="placeholder=${coche.matricula}"/>
                                </div>
                                </div>
                                
                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <button class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Cancelar</button>
                                    <input type="submit" value="Modificar" class="btn btn-primary float-right"/>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                            
                            
                        </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
                </div>
                <!-- fin delete modal-->
                
                
</body>


</html>
```

Archivo librerias el cual tambien se inserta y funciona bien:

```
    <div th:fragment="librerias">
    
    <!-- LIBRERIAS  -->
    <!-- LIBRERIAS  --> 
    <!-- LIBRERIAS  --> 
    <!-- LIBRERIAS  -->
    <!-- Custom fonts for this template -->
     
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">
 
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-cVKIPhGWiC2Al4u+LWgxfKTRIcfu0JTxR+EQDz/bgldoEyl4H0zUF0QKbrJ0EcQF"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
    
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

     
 

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
      <script>
          $( function() {
                $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({dateFormat:'dd/mm/yy'});
              } );
      </script>    
      
      <script>
          $( function() {
                $( "#datepicker2" ).datepicker({dateFormat:'dd/mm/yy'});
              } );
      </script>     
      
      <script>
      
      function comprobar()
      {   
          if (document.getElementById("habilitador").checked)
            document.getElementById('datepicker2').disabled = false;
              
          else
            document.getElementById('datepicker2').disabled = true;
              
      }
      </script>    
    
    
    
    
    
    <!-- FONT AWESOME  -->
    
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/6fcc8fb59a.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script>
    
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#show_hide_password a").on('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        if($('#show_hide_password input').attr("type") == "text"){
            $('#show_hide_password input').attr('type', 'password');
            $('#show_hide_password i').addClass( "fa-eye-slash" );
            $('#show_hide_password i').removeClass( "fa-eye" );
        }else if($('#show_hide_password input').attr("type") == "password"){
            $('#show_hide_password input').attr('type', 'text');
            $('#show_hide_password i').removeClass( "fa-eye-slash" );
            $('#show_hide_password i').addClass( "fa-eye" );
        }
    });
});
    
    </script>  
    
    </div>
```

Una imagen para que veais las rutas (donde intento insertar top es en coches.html, y los estilos que intento insertar en top es styles.css):
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He de decir que en la consola de spring no me aparece ningun error, el codigo top se inserta y se aplican los estilos bootstrap pero no los styles.css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

si estas usando thymeleaf te aconsejo que hagas los imports con su notación:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/css/bootstrap.min.css}">
<link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/css/style.css}">
```

Haciendo el import de la css no hace falta que marques la carpeta "static" ya que es ahí donde va a buscar el recurso con hacer el import como te indico suficiente